# pushing back an array of objects into a vector c++

Tags: c++

I have a class which takes an array and repopulates the array with the same numbers in random positions. 
I now need generate a list that that generates 10 lists of the randomised array, which i believe i have done. 
I done this by creating an array of my class object as seen in my code.

```
class numbers{
    private:
    int indexCount;

    public:
    void swap (int *a, int *b)  
{  
    int temp = *a;  
    *a = *b;  
    *b = temp;  
}  
void printArray (int arr[], int n)  
{  
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  
    cout << arr[i] << " ";  
    cout << "random calls: " << indexCount <<endl; 

}  
  void randomize (int arr[], int n)  
{  

   indexCount=0;
    for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--)  
    {  
        int j = rand() % (i + 1);  
        indexCount++;
        swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);  

    }  
}


};

       int main()
       {

        srand (time(NULL));
        vector <int> list;

            int i;
            int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0};  
            int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);  
           numbers a[10]; 
            for (i=0; i <10;i++)
            {
            a[i].randomize(arr,n);
            a[i].printArray(arr,n); 
        //  list.push_back(a[i]);

            }


return 0;


       }
```

What i am trying to do is is push back the array of object a that contains each list into the list vector such that list[1] would contain {1,0,2,3,0,0,6,5,4} and list[2] would contain another set of numbers.

My question:
how could i push back the array of objects that contain the list of numbers into my vector.

for example:
input:
{1,2,3,4,5,6,0,0,0}
output after printing off the vector
list[0] contains {1,0,2,3,0,0,6,5,4}
list[1] contains {0,0,1,6,0,4,3,5,2}
           ...
list[9] contains {1,0,2,0,3,4,6,5,0}

Comment: Hi @elie1 and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [ask] if you haven't already. Your question appears to be missing a question. Does your code compile? If so, does it produce the correct output? Please include a sample input, expected output, and actual output. If it's a debugging question, please read [example].

Comment: Thankyou john i will edit my question now

Comment: So you want each element in the vector to contain it's own array. Would it be acceptable for you if each vector contained its own vector? Vectors are better than arrays, and unless you're writing very high speed low-level code, you should use vectors over arrays.

Comment: yes exactly, this is for a uni task and they asked for the numbers to be stored into an array and then generate the list 10 times and store it into a single vector. So i thought that if i could make an object that contains each list and then pass that object into the vector that would work

Comment: @elie1 Your object _doesn't_ contain the list, though. You'd need `arr` to be class member for that.

Comment: @nick you are right, however i am a bit confused, could you please explain a little more. would it be something like a[i]=arr[i] after my randomise function?

Comment: `a[i]` and `arr[i]` are not compatible types, one is `numbers` the other is `int`. I think you don't quite understand how classes work, so I'd suggest not using them. It's definitely the more difficult solution to this problem. My solution would be to just create 10 arrays in `main` and store them in your `list`, then shuffle them.

Comment: My other idea was to have a 10 vectors that each contain one array then have a vector of a vector to store each vector. Is that an efficient way? I am also unable to use a shuffle function

Comment: A vector cannot contain an array. A vector can contain a pointer to the start of an array (but this would require you to use `new[]` and `delete[]` which I do NOT recommend as a beginner. Or a vector can contain `int`s. What you probably want is a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A vector cannot be templated with a standard array (such as `int a[10]`). It can be templated with a pointer (such as `int *`) and it can be templated with another `std::vector`.

If you have an array, and you want to store the values of that array in a single index of a vector, you need to copy the elements of the array into the container in the vector. For a `std::vector<int*>` this looks like this:

```
    std::vector<int*> array_vec;
    int numbers[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 20};
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int* temp = new int[sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(numbers[0])];
        std::copy(&numbers[0], &numbers[9], temp);
        array_vec.push_back(temp);

        // change numbers so that it's different and we can see that reflected in the output
        numbers[8] = i;
    }

    // print the elements from the vector
    for (auto a : array_vec)
    {
        std::cout << "{ ";
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            std::cout << a[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "}\n";
    }

    // we need to delete the memory we allocated
    for (auto a : array_vec)
        delete[] a;
```

**Note:** I do not recommend this method, since it requires the use of `new[]` and `delete[]`. There is no reason in modern C++ that you should be manually managing memory like this, especially as a beginner.

The better solution is to use a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`. No manual memory management. You take advantage of the `std::vector<int>` constructor that takes two iterators for `int`, a start and an end iterator, and `emplace_back` (instead of `push_back`):

```
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vector_vec;
    int numbers[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 20};
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        // create a new std::vector<int> in vector_vec by calling its iterator constructor
        vector_vec.emplace_back(numbers, numbers + 9);

        numbers[8] = i;
    }

    // print the elements from the vector
    for (auto& v : vector_vec)
    {
        std::cout << "{ ";
        for (auto i : v)
        {
            std::cout << i << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "}\n";
    }
```

**Note:** There is no need now to manually `delete[]` the memory, since the `std::vector` manages memory for us.

---

This answer does not address the issues with the class in your question. That will have to be answered in a different question, if you have one.

If you have questions about the `std::vector` class, its constructors, or its member functions, please see [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).